# How to use max and group by statement on my SQL query?

Tags: sql

```
task_name         start_time            value
acc_clock         2010-05-27              4
icc_opy           2010-05-28              5
icc_dtaf          2010-05-29              3
acc_clock         2010-05-25             34
icc_ruty          2010-05-23             33
icc_ruty          2010-05-22             45
```

This is my output of a SQL query which is coming from two different tables. Note that in this output, `task_name` is occuring twice. Now I want the output to have only one occurence of `task_name` and its associated value should be the maximum `start_time`, like this:

```
task_name         start_time            value
icc_opy           2010-05-28              5
icc_dtaf          2010-05-29              3
acc_clock         2010-05-25             34
icc_ruty          2010-05-23             33
```

My query is

```
select t.task_name, 
            max(t.start_time) , 
            i.value
from    task_runs t,
            integer_values i 
where i.run_id= t.id 
    and t.username= 'amit' 
    and t.start_time > '2010-05-20' 
order by t.task_name 
 group by t.task_name?????????
```

---

Why my query is not working?

My values coming from two tables : task_runs, integer_value. I want these three columns but task name with max start_time with associated its value.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your current statement

- `ORDER BY`must be placed *after* a `GROUP BY`
- You either have to add `i.value` to the `GROUP BY` clause or use an aggregate function (MIN, MAX, AVG, ...) on `i.value`

#### SQL Statement

```
    select  t.task_name
            , max(t.start_time) 
            , i.value 
    from    task_runs t
            , integer_values i 
    where   i.run_id= t.id 
            and t.username= 'amit' 
            and t.start_time > '2010-05-20' 
    group by 
            t.task_name
            , i.value
    order by 
            t.task_name
```

#### SQL Statement (Edit)

```
select  t.task_name
        , t.start_time
        , i.value
from    (
          select  t.task_name
                  , start_time = max(t.start_time) 
          from    task_runs t
          where   t.username= 'amit' 
                  and t.start_time > '2010-05-20' 
          group by 
                  t.task_name
        ) tm
        INNER JOIN task_runst t ON t.task_name = tm.task_name AND t.start_time = tm.start_time        
        INNER JOIN integer_values i ON i.run_id = t.id        

order by 
        t.task_name
```

Comment: buddy i have tried this,  but one thing is, its giving me output same as previously it was coming. 
Because if a task is coming two times with two different values than, in the output it is showing me both.
but i want that it should care about value just print it but with max date time and associted task name ????????????? 
help me its important????????
 But if a task is coming twice but both time with same value than only it is giving me single record with max time.

Comment: @user970553 - Rereading your question, I have added a revised statement. A subquery is needed to first retrieve only the needed records from task_runs and attach to them the integer_values (I assume that run_id is unique in the task_runs table).

Comment: @user970553 - and the use of multiple interrogation marks is really not necessary. All it does is actually *refrain* people from helping.

Comment: You might have duplicates on `task_name` (different `t.id` same `t.task_name`). You might have duplicates on `start_time` (same task started twice simultaneously). You might have several (or none) `integer_values` for a given `t.id`.

Comment: @wqw - I mentioned (in comments) that I assume t.id to be unique. Duplicates on start time are possible but it doesn't show in the input from OP. I also assumed one integer_value (run_id) for a given task. If these assumptions don't hold, OP should adjust his question to reflect all this but I assume (pun intended :) they are correct.

Comment: @wqw - No but I do assume the combination `t.task_name, t.start_time` to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` must go before `ORDER BY` and you should choose what value of `i.value` do you want (max, min, ...).

Comment: if a task is coming two times with two different values than, in the output it is showing me both. but i want that it should not care about value just print the associated value with it but with max date time and associted task name ????????????? help me its important???????? But if a task is coming twice but both time with same value than only it is giving me single record with max time. if i remove i.value from query then it is giving me perfect output but only with two columns but i need this value column also.

Answer (score 0):

On MSSQL try this

```
SELECT      t.id
            , MAX(t.task_name) AS task_name
            , MAX(t.start_time) AS start_time
            , (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM integer_values WHERE run_id = t.id) AS value
FROM        task_runs t
WHERE       t.username = 'amit' 
            AND t.start_time > '20100520' 
GROUP BY    t.id
ORDER BY    task_name
```